# math_3d.h with opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, g++

So, I was reading http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial02/tutorial02.html and it said I needed math_3d.h for Vector3f.

I tried to include it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "GL/glew.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/freeglut.h"

#include "math_3d.h"

void render() {
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  glutSwapBuffers();

  glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
  glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
  glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
  glutCreateWindow("OpenGL - First window demo");

  /* Set  */
  GLenum res = glewInit();
  if (res != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: '%s'\n", glewGetErrorString(res));
    return 1;
  }

  Vector3f vertices[1];

  glutDisplayFunc(render);
  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

G++ said "main.cpp:7:21: fatal error: math_3d.h: No such file or directory". I looked for an Arch Linux package for it, but I found nothing.

I found the file here:

http://ogldev.googlecode.com/svn-history/r75/trunk/tutorial36/math_3d.h

Am I supposed to download that file and place it my project directory, or is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Also, if I do include it in my directory, how can I add it to the g++ line?

```
gcc main.cpp -o main -lGLEW -lglut -lGL
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I supposed to download that file and place it my project directory?

Yes

Comment: Doesn't that file have a license or something that I need to include when I open source my project on github or something?

Comment: Read the top of the file, it tells you the license info.

Comment: Thank you, I shall include the LICENSE file.

Comment: ** Building...
gcc main.cpp -o main -lGLEW -lglut -lGL
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccTeoYur.o: undefined reference to symbol '__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '__gxx_personality_v0@@CXXABI_1.3' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1

I am getting this error, though :S

Answer (score 2):

It's sufficient download the file in your directory. Is not required to add it to gcc command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have to download it, if you need this library in more than one project you can save it in /usr/include and use it as a C library with `#include <math_3d.h>`, avoiding to copy it in every single project's directory.